# error after upgrading spring and hibernate s

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [java.lang.Object]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineCollectionType(AttributeFactory.java:982)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.(AttributeFactory.java:827)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.(AttributeFactory.java:808)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:587)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:92)

that coming from this component:

[component xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fL0x.png)

old hibernate 5.0.2 new 5.6.15
old spring 5.3.22 new  5.3.31

tried to replace the bag with set/list/map

Comment: ANd you expect an answer without knowing the versions, your code, your configuration etc. etc.? We need more information then this.

Comment: Please format your code for better readability. Also share numbers of Spring and Hibernate from and to which you want to upgrade.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: fixed added all the details